# xamarin Forms and webview not using the correct class

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

when I submit my app to testflight I get the following warning.
(I am using the latest version of Xamarin forms and Xamarin Essentials)

App Store Connect

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "XXXXXXXX" 18.8.0 (18.8.0.89). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - App updates that use UIWebView will no longer be accepted as of December 2020. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Best regards,

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: As stated by the OP, this is resolved in the latest version of forms. Therefore, I'm voting to close the question as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the document about [UIWebView Deprecation and App Store Rejection (ITMS-90809)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809) and make sure your project has meet all the requirement:

A preview version of the linker is available to fix this issue. To enable the preview, you will need to supply an additional argument --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type to the linker.

The prerequisites for this to work are:

- Xamarin.Forms 4.5 or higher. Xamarin.Forms 4.6, or higher, is
  required if your app uses Material Visual.
- Xamarin.iOS 13.10.0.17 or higher. Check your Xamarin.iOS version in
  Visual Studio. This version of Xamarin.iOS is included with Visual
  Studio for Mac 8.4.1 and Visual Studio 16.4.3.
- Remove references to UIWebView. Your code should not have any
  references to UIWebView or any classes that make use of UIWebView.